Terminal failures installing Eclipse Bash Editor Windows 10
I am using Eclipse 2022-12 on Windows 10.  I installed GitBash for Windows. I installed the Bash Editor from the Marketplace.  When I run a file.sh, an external console window will flicker briefly but the script will fail.  I am able to run the script directly in a Git Bash terminal.
Here is a screenshot of Windows < Preferences < Bash Editor Launch.  The following images Show result cmd and Test Terminal, where the Test Terminal is the external console window and lingers for a few seconds (enough to get the image).
eclipse bashed launch configuration
bashed external terminal
I expected that when I did a right-click Run as bash on a file.sh, it would execute that bash script and write the output file the script produces.

Eclipse 2022-12 is five releases behind. Please upgrade and support the open source software you use by providing feedback on the latest version only.

I tried this on Eclipse RCP and RAP Latest (2024-06) and got the same behavior.

There is no 2024-06 yet and your question is still about an Eclipse that is five(!) releases behind.

I switched to EasyShell.  The preferences are configured from a list of various shells, commands to be shown when right-clicking on a file (in my case Run with Git Bash v2.x.)

Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2024-06 M2 (4.32.0 M2)
Build id: 20240502-0722
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
Java runtime version: 22.0.1+8
Java version: 22.0.1

On a closing note, the issue may be related to using WSL in some way.  I tried configuring it to use Windows COM as the Terminal, but it seemed to auto-detect Ubuntu and git-bash.exe.

M2 means second milestone. Please edit and improve your question or delete it.
